# How do you upgrade rubygems from a war file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, jruby, war, warbler

I'm working with an older system, (jruby 1.6.8, rails 2.3.5, tomcat 7, centos 7, java 1.7), and I need to downgrade rubygems from 1.8.24 to 1.4.2. I don't know java/jruby well enough to know how exactly to do this. My development environment I was able to accomplish this with:

```
gem update --system 1.4.2
```

But no idea how that is done after you build a war file. I'm using warbler (0.9.14) to build the war file.

Any thoughts would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

updating might have been possible if there was a .gem release of rubygems and setting:  `config.gems["rubygems"] = "1.4.2"` ... guess that brings in the oldest problem - the chicken-egg one so I do not think there's an easy way like this.

jruby is packed from jars one of which contains the stdlib files - thus by replacing the .jar with a one that updates RG you might get what you strike for.

Comment: What that's what I was trying to avoid. It's fine now though, I ended up patching rails :(